# Are values set inside a loop lost once the loop is over?

Tags: java

I'm doing an online course by the name of "Object-Oriented programming with Java"

And I can't figure out [exercise 36](http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part1/material-2013/week-2?noredirect=1)..

> Create a program that asks the user to input numbers (integers). The program prints "Type numbers” until the user types the number -1. When the user types the number -1, the program prints "Thank you and see you later!" and the sum of the numbers entered by the user (without the number -1).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopsEndingRemembering {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (n != -1) {
            System.out.println("Type numbers");
            n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            sum = sum + n; // <-- The value set here is tossed once the loop of over?..
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum); // <-- Does not acknowledge the free state of 'loop' and any variables that come of it        
    }
}
```

So when I click the 'Run tests locally' (it's a plugin 
button) in Netbeans I'm getting:

> With input 1 -1  you should print "the sum is 1" expected:<1> but was:<0>

The '0', to my understanding, is indicating that the last println only recognizes the initialization of 'sum'..why is that?..

Comment: You are subtracting the last -1 as well.

Comment: @Marvin is right: Your loop does the arithmetic *also* with -1. Add 1 to sum before you print it ( or print `++sum`)

Comment: In the example there's only a single number to be added (1) giving the total `sum` = 1. But, as others have said, you subtract the second input (-1) which only serves to stop the summing. Doing so gives you a sum of 0 when you should have 1 (as stated in the error message). IOW, you don't check the value of `n` before you add (or subtract) it from the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Change you while loop to check the users input as the last thing in the loop. Example:

```
public static void loopTest()
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Type a number then press enter... type '-1' to sum the numbers and exit");
    n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    while (n != -1)
    {
       sum = sum + n;
       n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    } 
    System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum ); // <-- Does   
}
```